# most generic lazy collection trait

Tags: scala, stream, scala-collections, traits

In Scala, probably the most generic Collection `trait` is `GenIterable`.  What's the most generic `trait` that specifies that a collection must be a "lazy-list", like a `Stream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection is `Stream` itself, and it's a class.
Indeed, the superclasses/traits of `Stream[A]` are the following:

- **AbstractSeq[A]**: No laziness required
- **LinearSeq[A]**: No laziness required
- **GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Stream]**: No laziness required
- **LinearSeqOptimized[A, Stream[A]]**: No laziness required
- **Serializable**: No laziness required

To ensure the laziness of a home-made iterable collection, you can use the following trait though:

```
trait GenLazyIterable[A, B <: GenLazyIterable[A, B]] {
  val head: A            // To implement
  private var computedTail: Option[B] = None
  protected def lazyTail: B  // To implement
  def tail: B = {
    if(computedTail.nonEmpty) computedTail.get
    else {
      val t = lazyTail
      computedTail = Some(t)
      t
    }
  }
}
```

Note the following:

- You cannot currently have abstract lazy vals directly in an abstract class or trait.
- AbstractSeq[A] cannot be inherited, since requires you to give the `length` property which obviously you cannot guarantee in an `GenLazyIterable`
- You can inherit `IterableLike` in order to use methods such as `foreach`, etc.